# Oozie action to run batch file

Tags: batch-file, hadoop, oozie

How to execute a batch file in oozie?

I have tried the below workflow. But it is not running.

```
<shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
              <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
              <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <exec>file.bat</exec>
        <argument>20</argument>
        <file>hdfs://machine1:9000/user/file.bat#file.bat</file>
</shell>
```

**Error**

```
Cannot run program "file.bat"
```

Can anyone help me to run batch file in oozie?

Comment: Are you trying to run a Windows .bat file on Linux, or do you have Oozie/Hadoop running on Windows?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @BinaryNerd Oozie/Hadoop running on windows.

Comment: @ManoDestra I am getting as Cannot run program "file.bat".

Comment: Are you able to run the bat manually? Do you get the same error if the bat file is empty? Or if the bat file does not exist on the right spot?

Comment: Batch file working manually. I have placed the batch in right spot.